# invite user by username to telegram channel

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, telegram, telethon

i trying to add users by usernames to my channel. I am using python 3.6 telethon library and pythonanywhere server:

```
api_hash = 'b7**'
phone = '+7***'
client = TelegramClient('new_ses', api_id, api_hash)
client.connect()
client = TelegramClient('session_neworig', api_id, api_hash,)
client.connect()

from telethon.tl.functions.channels import InviteToChannelRequest
from telethon.tl.functions.contacts import ResolveUsernameRequest
from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerChannel ,InputPeerUser,InputUser
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import JoinChannelRequest

chann=client.get_entity('channelname') #its public channel
print(chann.id)
1161823752

print(chann.access_hash)
8062085565372622341

time.sleep(30)
chan=InputPeerChannel(chann.id, chann.access_hash)
user = client(ResolveUsernameRequest('Chai***'))


print(user.users[0].id)
193568760
print(user.users[0].access_hash)
-4514649540347033311
time.sleep(1*30)

user=InputUser(user.users[0].id,user.users[0].access_hash,)

client.invoke(InviteToChannelRequest(chan,[user]))
```

This dosent work and i get `-telethon.errors.rpc_error_list.PeerFloodError: (PeerFloodError(...), 'Too many requests')`

what am i doing wrong? how to avoid it ?
this one code is worked for me , but i am gone to flood after added let's say 20 users :

```
 from telethon.helpers import get_input_peer

client.invoke(InviteToChannelRequest(
    get_input_peer(client.get_entity(chan),
    [get_input_peer(client.get_entity(user))]
))
```

Please help , how to add 200 users by username without any ban , maybe there is another way to do it by python ? another lib or by api ?

Comment: Don't spam in Telegram

Comment: @Sean i trying to add users from my channel to chat , i dont tink you can call it spam. and its only 200 users

Comment: Why don't you provide them join link?

Comment: because i am exploring telethon lib  and stuck at this method

Comment: Every method have its rate limit

Comment: It clearly said `Too Many Request`

Comment: @sean i ran it only ones  for one username and channel . how can be less request ?

Comment: @Sean  maybe you can tell me where can i look at this limits. but anyway i run it only ones and i dont get how i can use this method less then once

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: Did you already find an answer to this?

Comment: please update if you found the answer

Answer (score 1):

Found somethin on Telegram API documentation website

**Each phone number is limited to only a certain amount of logins per day (e.g. 5, but this is subject to change) after which the API will return a FLOOD error until the next day. This might not be enough for testing the implementation of User Authorization flows in client applications.**

[Link to source](https://core.telegram.org/api/auth)

Answer (score 0):

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import InviteToChannelRequest
from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerChannel ,InputUser
from telethon.tl.functions.contacts import ResolveUsernameRequest

api_id = ******
api_hash = '******'
phone = '+2519******'
client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash);
client.connect()


chann=client.get_entity('channelname') 
channel_id = chann.id;
channel_access_hash = chann.access_hash

chanal=InputPeerChannel(channel_id, channel_access_hash)
user = client(ResolveUsernameRequest('mrmi6'))

user=InputUser(user.users[0].id,user.users[0].access_hash,)
client(InviteToChannelRequest(chanal,[user]))
print('action completted')
```